# Terminology: 'pointwise monotone functional'?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

I have a set $\mathcal{F}$ of real-valued functions,
$$f_i(\cdot):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \, ,$$ 
and a (linear) functional $T$ defined on $\mathcal{F}$, 
$$T:f_i \mapsto T[f_i] \in \mathbb{R} \, ,$$
such that $$f_1(x)\geq f_2(x) \ \  \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow T[f_1] \geq T[f_2]\, .$$

Is there a standard term for this property? Can I call $T$ 'monotonic,' or 'pointwise monotonic'? (In particular, 'pointwise increasing'?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\mathcal F $ is a subspace and $T$ linear it called a **positive linear form**. as example $T(f)=\int_a^bf(t)dt$ with $a<b$ and $\mathcal F=\mathcal C([a,b],\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks!. Oops, I realize my $T$ is affine, not linear. Anyway this is close enough. I guess I can call the offset-subtracted part a **positive linear functional**.